# Infinite Limits: Why M>0?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ when for every $M>0$ there is $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>M$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Why do we include $M>0$ in the definition? For example, in the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|} - 3$, $M=-2$ still works for $\delta=1$?

Comment: You're right, we could write this definition with "$M\in \Bbb{R}$".

Comment: It is a convention, and there is no added value to allowing negative values of $M$. One could write for all $M > 42$, but again, the point is for large $M$ one can find a $d$ such that blah blah blah...

Comment: You're right, the formality here is that if you are trying to prove an infinite limit then you would construct a proof by choosing an $M>0$. If you were trying to prove an negative infinite limit then you would begin by choosing a $\delta > 0$ such that for $x$ approaching $c$ one would write $0<|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x) < -M$

Comment: You're right. What is not completely trivial is that from the general definition, it is **sufficient** to find $\delta$ for $M>0$, or $M$ "sufficiently large". It becomes clear when you learn a little more topology :-)

Comment: IMO, there is no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint in the case $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=+\infty$,

if the definition statement is true for each $ M>0$, then it will be true for each $A<0$ since we have for $x$ close to $a$, $f(x)>M>A$.